# How to run batch job for multiple extensions with find command?

Tags: bash, centos, batch-processing, jpegoptim

I am trying to use jpegoptim for optimizing all jpg and jpeg images on my server recursively.

This command is working:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg"   -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;
```

but i need something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.jpeg"   -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;
```

which is not working. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: `find . -type f -name "*.jp.*g"   -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" \) -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;
```

Comment: Those brackets are not needed.

Comment: the version with brackets works actually. please edit your answer as previous and i will accept your answer.

find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" \) -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;